# VSCode on Windows: gdb doesn't break on 'throw' but breaks on regular exceptions

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-7, gdb

While debugging my code, gdb catches regular exceptions (such as dividing by zero) but not custom ones, thrown with `throw`.

I'd expect vscode to jump where the exception is thrown, so i can investigate. Instead, the exception causes the application to terminate and the debugger to close.

I tested it with some dummy code:

compiled with: `g++ -g main.cpp -o test.exe`

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

void test()
{
    throw std::invalid_argument( "received negative value" );
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cin.get();

    // int c = 1 / 0;
    test();

    std::cout << "v";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  received negative value

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

---

My environment:

- Windows 7 64bit
- VSCode 1.40.2
- MinGW

launch.json

```
        {
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/test.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile",
            "externalConsole": true
        }
```

Comment: There is a workarround though. I can place a breakpoint, where the exception is thrown and then investigate.

Comment: accept,   please.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Sorry I lost this problem out of eyesight, cause my final workaround was to switch C++ development to Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For more info about `catch` see https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html#Set-Catchpoints

add to `launch.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "setupCommands": [
        /*{
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        },*/
        {
            "description": "Enable break on all exceptions",
            "text": "catch throw",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: can I have both? (pretty printing seems to enable stl debug much better)

Comment: @RanCohen Nothing is true; everything is permitted

Comment: I tried both in the text field. it did not work. can you show an example of how I can have both?

Comment: @RanCohen just remove `/*` and `*/`.